How to create car to car communication by using the D2D Multicast connection in simuLTE.omnet
I am trying to simulate car-to-car communication by using  D2D Multicast configuration, to do this  I have considered the number of vehicles to be 30  and  I want to establish D2D multicast communication for this number of vehicles. I should also say that I'm using my custom sumo map (not using the default sumo map heterogeneous). Therefore, I configured the ini.file of my project like this:
 ### Enable D2D for the eNodeB and the UEs involved in direct communications ### *.eNodeB*.nicType = "LteNicEnbD2D" 
*.car[*].nicType = "LteNicUeD2D" 
**.amcMode = "D2D"  
### Select CQI for D2D transmissions ### 
# One-to-Many communications work with fixed CQI values only. 
# Set the parameter **.usePreconfiguredTxParams and select the desired CQI using the parameter **.d2dCqi 

**.enableD2DCqiReporting = false 
**.usePreconfiguredTxParams = true 
**.d2dCqi = ${cqi=7}  
### Traffic configuration ### 
*.car[*].numApps = 1 
 # --- 1st group: 0 < 1 < 2 < 3 -- 30# 
*.car[0..30].ipv4.configurator.mcastGroups = "224.0.0.10" 
# transmitter 
*.car[0].app[*].typename = "AlertSender" 
*.car[0].app[*].localPort = 3088+ancestorIndex(0) 
*.car[0].app[*].startTime = uniform(0s,0.02s) 
*.car[0].app[*].destAddress = "224.0.0.10"    # IP address of the multicast group  *.car[0].app[*].destPort = 1000 # receivers 
*.car[1..29].app[*].typename = "AlertReceiver" 
*.car[1..29].app[*].localPort = 1000 

On the other hand, as mentioned in the readme.txt of the D2DMulticast, I have set the multicast cast group in demo.xml
<multicast-group hosts="car[*]" interfaces="wlan" address="224.0.0.10"/>

According to the mentioned cases, when the simulation is executed, I encounter the following error:
check_and_cast(): Cannot cast nullptr to type 'LteMacEnbD2D*' --in module (LteMacUeD2D) Highway.car[1].cellularNic.mac (id=409), at t=21.115s,event#311606  


My question is how should correctly D2D multicast communication be made for 30 cars? why does this error appear in 20 seconds of simulation? How should I fix this error?
I greatly appreciate any help!
I referred to the module mentioned in the error, but I don't know what changes I need to make.
